# logback log files to a unified file path

Tags: java, logback

In my spring web app, I'm using logback.

I want to put all log files to application's root folder, i.e.

`{MyApplicationFolderPath}/output/logs`

where `{MyApplicationFolderPath}`, depending on the platform of server, may be placed anywhere.

I have this definition in the `logback.xml`:

```
<property name="LOG_HOME" value="../output/logs" />
```

But when I am on a windows platform, I can't find where the folder goes to. In java code, I would use something like:

```
{someClass}.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath()
```

But I don't know how to do this in the `logback.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using just `/output/logs` then it must be printing logs under `C:/output/logs` (C -> Drive Letter).

If you are on Linux and want the Logs to be printed inside your Project Directory then you can change it to `../output/logs` instead.

If you are on Windows then you can provide the absolute path to your base directory or do something like `./output/logs/MyLogs.log`. Latter should create the `output/logs/` directory under your Project Directory at `src` level.

Comment: My logback.xml is under WEB-INF/classes folder, and I do see this line: File property is set to [../output/logs/error.log] but I can't find the log folder under the WEB-INF folder though, and I can't find where it is now.. lol.

Comment: In the code you have provided, the value is set to `/output/logs` and not `../output/logs`.

Comment: Sorry I mean after changing int to value="../output/logs" as you suggested.

Comment: Try providing an absolute path of the directory where you want to print the Logs. For Example, `C:/MyApps/SomeApp/Output/Logs`

Comment: That will make the path platform dependent: linux has no idea what is C:\

Comment: Okay. So you want to deploy the same project to Linux also. Does it print the logs in `C:/output/logs` when you didn't change the log4j value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102104/discussion-between-user2004685-and-jamesdeath123).